# Producing dynamically generated range names in Excel using c#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

What is the best way to produce several tables of unknown size on the same worksheet?  Values will be pulled from an oracle database and are used as values on several tables.   Is it possible to create dynamic named ranges or is some other method desirable?  I have some experience with c# but do not have access to VSTO 2005.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I am willing to explain the problem further if requested.

Comment: Yes, you should explain further. No, you don't need VSTO at all, so don't worry about that. You should put one table per worksheet, or else you will have to be incredibly careful to not have them interfere. I don't see the need for a "dynamic named range", which in Excel parlance is typically a type of a Worksheet formula. You can name cells and ranges whatever you want, but these are just aliases. You can name the range "A1:C3" to be "MyRange" and then use that in formulas, but this is rarely of value when using code. I think you need to explain more about what you are trying to do...

Comment: ... If you give us a better sense of the big picture, there will be a better chance that someone could help you out.

Comment: "You can name the range "A1:C3" to be "MyRange" and then use that in formulas, but this is rarely of value when using code." Are you kidding me. One of the most valued technique programming against Excel is "named ranges".

Comment: @AMissico: you are 100% right, I don't know what I was thinking. My original comment is almost 5 years old, is so far off that I have to correct it: Named ranges are extremely valuable both in worksheet formulas and in code. Even more so in code to prevent insertion or deletion of rows/columns from changing the meaning of your range references. My apologies to Matey or anyone I may have confused by my original answer. In the case of a table, however, a named-range is automatically made for you and it dynamically resizes for you as well.

Comment: I would definitely try to keep only one table per worksheet if at all possible. Next best is to arrange them left to right -- don't put one table below another unless you are sure they will never need to be resized. (And even be careful of a left-to-right arrangement if columns might ever need to be added.) Again, best for Tables and Pivot Tables to be one per worksheet if at all possible.

Comment: @MikeRosenblum, lessons learned through experience are the best lessons, but they can be hard won. It is refreshing to see someone publicly correcting themselves.

Comment: Thanks AMissico. I honestly don't know what I was thinking there, I wish I had caught this immediately instead of years later.

Answer (score 1):

Open a blank excel file, make a sample of the result what you would like to get and save it in XML. 
Use that file as a base/template for generating your XML.

Pros:

- It doesn't require Excel to be installed on the machine to generate it the XML.
- It doesn't create and instance of an Excel Object
- It doesn't make calls to the Excel COM object (usually expensive)

Cons:

- I don't know if it's possible to create more than one worksheet    :)

In a ASP.NET, you can build it and can declare in the header the content-type as application/vnd.ms-excel. That way will most browsers will understand its an Excel find and will try opening with Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the current value of the lowest cell block being used, and keep adding the tables growing down, or like Mike Rosenblum said, making multiple sheets in the same workbook would make the document a lot less bloated. Let me know if I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a range object that should be named
2. assign a name to its Name property
3. assign a values or a value[,] to the Value2 property

   ```
   object[,] values = { { 111, 222, 333 }, { 444, 555, 666 }, { 101, 202, 303 }, 
                        { 404, 505, 606 }, { 111, 222, 333 }, { 444, 555, 666 },
                        { 101, 202, 303 }, { 404, 505, 606 } };

   Application excel = new Application();
   Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);
   Worksheet sheet = (Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets[1];

   int rows = values.GetUpperBound(0) - values.GetLowerBound(0) + 1;
   int cols = values.GetUpperBound(1) - values.GetLowerBound(1) + 1;

   // assign a name to an area of cells and fill it with values
   Range dest = sheet.get_Range(sheet.Cells[1, 1], sheet.Cells[rows, cols]);
   dest.Name = "SORUCE_RANGE";
   dest.Value2 = values;

   // assign a name to a single cell
   dest = (Range) sheet.Cells[5, 7];
   dest.Name = "MY_DESTINATION";
   dest.NumberFormatLocal = "TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm:ss"; //german format syntax
   dest.Value2 = DateTime.Now;

   // clean up (best in finally block)
   workbook.Close(false, null, null);
   excel.Quit();
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
   ```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your requirements, it seems you want to use a List or Table for each table. Think of list as a small database table stored within a worksheet. You can refer to the list's range, you can add records, delete records, insert additional columns, and so on.

What you can do is define a list for each table, generate the data, then insert that data into the list.

> List Management – Data/ List/ Create
>   List or Ctrl+L applies list tools to
>   lists in Excel.  List range is marked
>   with a resizable blue border. 
>   Features include AutoFilter headers,
>   Insert Row and Total Row.  List can be
>   imported/exported to both XML and
>   SharePoint sources.

You can find VBA code examples for Tables in Excel 2007 or a List in Excel 2003 at http://www.rondebruin.nl/tablecode.htm